# Applying tf.gather to all rows of two tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to apply `tf.gather()` to all the rows of a given parameters tensor and an indices tensor.

I can apply `tf.gather()` on two 1D tensors to extract a 1D tensor:

```
# params == array([3, 8, 9, 7, 6])
# inds == array([1, 2, 3])

>>> tf.gather(params, inds).eval()
array([8, 9, 7])
```

Now what if I have two 2D tensors, and want to apply `tf.gather()` on them row-wise? I want something like this:

```
# params == array([[3, 8, 9, 7, 6],
#                  [6, 1, 7, 0, 7],
#                  [7, 4, 4, 5, 8]])

# inds == array([[1, 2, 3],
#                [2, 3, 4],
#                [0, 1, 2]])

>>> row_wise_gather(params, inds)
array([[8, 9, 7],
       [7, 0, 7],
       [7, 4, 4]]
```

The closest I've come so far is using `tf.gather()` with `axis=1`, which yields a 3D tensor, and then index the result with `gather_nd()`:

```
>>> gathered3d = tf.gather(params, inds, axis=1)
# gathered3d == array([[[8, 9, 7],
#                       [9, 7, 6],
#                       [3, 8, 9]],
#
#                      [[1, 7, 0],
#                       [7, 0, 7],
#                       [6, 1, 7]],
#
#                      [[4, 4, 5],
#                       [4, 5, 8],
#                       [7, 4, 4]]])

>>> tf.gather_nd(gathered3d, [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]).eval()
array([[8, 9, 7],
       [7, 0, 7],
       [7, 4, 4]])
```

(I'd call other functions instead of giving literal values, but that's beside the point and not an issue)

This is very clumsy. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

By the way, the indices I use are always values increasing one by one; each row just has a different start and end value. That might make the problem easier.